# Is the mean value theorem the method for this VTRMC 1985 Question?

Tags: calculus, contest-math

[image]

This question looks like me value theorem by canceling of a way to apply it in the problem quite yet. An image I messed around with the given equation and tried to set it equal to the second derivative but it I came up with nothing. I'm suspecting that my method to solve this problem is incorrect.

Comment: Hint: Let $y=f(x)$ and the condition becomes a DE: $$y'+b=\frac{2(y-a)}{x-c} $$ with $a=f(c), b=f'(c)$. It is easy to solve. Once you obtain $y=f(x)$, you can verify $f''(x)=\cdots$.

Comment: The mean value theorem only state there exist some $c'$ such that specific equation holds. (Note that this $c'$ should be different from the given $c$, although the letter $c$ is frequently used for this theorem.) It seems difficult to utilize the theorem because the requirement is about the given $c$, not about some $c'$.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much for both of your replies!!!